# Raspberry PI Connect2 Pi not installing required drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, raspberry-pi

I recently got a RPi with different modules. One of them was a Connect2 Pi wireless dongle from LPRS, used to send 100 Mb data packages over the internet. It's basically an internet dongle. However, it does not work. According to the LPRS staff the drivers required for the dongle should be installed when you plug it in. However it doesn't do that.

I wonder what my mistake is and how to fix it (if it is fixable).

Comment: Do you know which chipset the dongle uses?

Comment: What distro are you running on the RPi?

Answer (score 1):

The dongle is likely not to work if plugged directly into the pi - the pi's USB ports provide very little power, and you *have* to use a *high quality* powered USB hub - I found that I have to do this even for using a wireless keyboard and flash drive at the same time (using one of these alone and its ok though). See [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals) for a list of verified hubs that work. Believe me cheap ones don't work.

Comment: Yeah I know! However this is a dongle specially designed for raspberry-pi and should work in the raspberry pi's usb ports. However I have tried with a powered usb hub and it doesn't work. This is the website for this dongle [link](http://www.lprs.co.uk/easy-radio/era-connect2-pi.html) and yes, I know it's not a wifi dongle!

Comment: If you're certain that was a verified usb hub, then it may be the distribution or kernel you are using.

Comment: What power supply are you using? The pi alone uses 700 mA, and anything over that on the power supply is then supposedly used for USB power through the ports. A typical smart phone charger is 1A, and that left over 300 mA would barely be enough for a wireless dongle, and that's if that entire 300mA reaches the dongle (not likely).

Comment: Hadn't heard of this device, so I looked it up finally - shows a power draw of 35 mA so it should work fine. Are you sure it's not working in the pi, or is it the other end that's not working? Is the other end in your PC?